# PHPUnit Autoload - No such file or directory

Tags: phpunit

Install:

```
pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

After manipulation broken uninstall 
Reinstalling does not help.

```
/usr/share/pear$ pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
uninstall ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-4.0.9
```

but, you still see after installation Autoload.php file still does not appear (((

```
 Fatal error: main(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/bin:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/pear/PEAR')
```

I do not understand how to get to work through phpunit.phar therefore tried to install via pear and even overthrown files directly from GitHub developer.

'm Confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run only CLI, not from web .....

Comment: This is not a real answer. Please add something to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the Bootstrap file to include the Autoloader and your directories.

My sample:

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is used to configure the basic environment for testing in PHPUnit.
 */

// PHP and Web server settings
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set("America/Toronto");       // Set the default timezone
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'http://myserver';       // Set Web Server name

// Process the Include Path to allow the additional application to be set.
$IncludePaths = explode( PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path() );
$NewIncludePaths = array_merge( $IncludePaths, array(dirname(__FILE__) ));
set_include_path( implode( PATH_SEPARATOR, array_unique($NewIncludePaths)));    // Update Include Path
?>
```

You then need to specify the bootstrap file when you start PHPUnit. 
[phpunit --bootstrap bootstrap.php](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/textui.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also found it a bit annoying to find the Autoloader file.

Mine was located at `/usr/share/php/pear/share/pear/PHPUnit/Autoload.php`

So I updated my php.ini file to include it `include_path=".:/usr/share/php/PEAR:/usr/share/php/pear/share/pear"`